# Php script into WordPress as page template

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to integrate bought php script (yougrabber) into WordPress as page template.

Script works fine as standalone website. But when I try to insert it as a page template and open it I get the following error:

> Warning: require_once(application/config/routes.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/yougrabber/core/router.php
>   on line 55
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'application/config/routes.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php')
>   in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/yougrabber/core/router.php
>   on line 55

I think that script is expected to be loaded in root directory.

And this is how scripts index.php looks when I put it in theme directory and tell wp it is a page template.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: TESTIRANJE
*/
?>
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL); //uncomment for development server

define("BASE_PATH", str_replace("\\", NULL, dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]) == "/" ? NULL : dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])) . '/');

require_once "core/router.php";

Router::init();

function __autoload($class) { Router::autoload($class); }

Router::route();
?>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: 
router.php

```
<?php
class Router
{
    private static $current_page;
    private static $page_struct;
    private static $is_router_loaded;

    private function __construct()
    {
        self::$current_page = self::getPage();
        self::$page_struct = explode("/", self::$current_page);
        self::$page_struct = array_values(array_filter(self::$page_struct, 'strlen'));
    }

    public static function init()
    {
        if(self::$is_router_loaded instanceof Router) return self::$is_router_loaded;

        else return self::$is_router_loaded = new Router;
    }

    public static function route()
    {
        self::loadAutoload();

        if(!self::getController())
        {
            try {
                self::loadDefaultPage();
            }
            catch(ConfigException $e) { return self::error404(); }
        }

        self::loadRewrites();
        self::loadPostedPage();
    }

    private static function loadDefaultPage()
    {
        require('application/config/routes.php');

        if(!is_array($routes["default_page"])) throw new ConfigException();

        else
        {
            $controller_cname = 'application\\Controllers\\'.$routes['default_page'][0];
            $controller_obj = new $controller_cname;
            $controller_obj->$routes['default_page'][1]();
        }
        exit;
    }

    private static function loadAutoload()
    {
        require_once("application/config/routes.php");
        require_once("/application/config/autoload.php");

        $loader =\core\Loader::getInstance(true);

        foreach($autoload['libraries'] as $library)
        {
            $loader->library($library);
        }
        foreach(array_unique($autoload['controllers']) as $controller)
        {
           if((strtolower(self::getController()) != strtolower($controller)) && (self::getController() != null && $routes['default_page'][0] == 'users')) $loader->controller($controller);
        }
    }

    private static function loadRewrites()
    {
        require("application/config/routes.php");

        foreach ($routes as $rewrittenPage => $realPage)
        {
            if(is_array($realPage)) continue;

            if($rewrittenPage == str_replace(BASE_PATH, NULL, $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) self::setPage($realPage);

            else if(preg_match_all('#\[(.*)\]#U', $rewrittenPage, $param_names))
            {
                $getRegex = preg_replace("#\[.*\]#U", "(.*)", $rewrittenPage);
                preg_match_all("#^\/?".$getRegex."$#", self::$current_page, $param_values); unset($param_values[0]);
                if(in_array(null, $param_values)) continue;

                else
                {
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach($param_values as $p_value)
                    {
                        $realPage = str_replace('['.$param_names[1][$i].']', $param_names[1][$i].':'.$p_value[0], $realPage);
                        $i++;
                    }
                    self::setPage($realPage);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static function loadPostedPage()
    {
        if(self::getController() != null && $controller = self::getController())
        {
            $controller = "application\\Controllers\\".$controller;
            $controller = new $controller;

            if(!self::getMethod())
            {
                if(method_exists($controller, 'index'))
                {
                    $controller->index();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $method = self::getMethod();

                if(!method_exists($controller, $method)) return self::error404();

                $method_data = new ReflectionMethod($controller, $method);

                if($method_data->isPublic() == true)
                {
                    if(!self::getParameters())
                    {
                        if($method_data->getNumberOfRequiredParameters() == 0) $controller->$method(); else self::error404();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $parametersToSet = self::getParameters();
                        $sortParams = array();

                        foreach($method_data->getParameters() as $params)
                        {
                            if(!$params->isOptional() && !isset($parametersToSet[$params->getName()])) return self::error404 ();

                            if($params->isOptional() && !isset($parametersToSet[$params->getName()])) $sortParams[] = $params->getDefaultValue();
                            else $sortParams[] = $parametersToSet[$params->getName()];
                        }
                        $method_data->invokeArgs($controller, $sortParams);
                    }
                } else return self::error404();
            }
        }
    }

    public static function error404()
    {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        die(file_get_contents('application/errors/404.html'));
        exit;
    }

    public static function autoload($className)
    {
        if(class_exists($className)) return true;

        else
        {
            $className = strtolower(str_replace('\\', '/', $className));
            if(!file_exists($className.'.php')) return self::error404();;

            require_once $className .'.php';
        }
    }

    private static function getController()
    {
        if(isset(self::$page_struct[0]))
            return self::$page_struct[0];
    }

    private static function getMethod()
    {
        if(isset(self::$page_struct[1]))
            return self::$page_struct[1];
    }

    private static function getParameters()
    {
        $parameters = array();

        foreach(self::$page_struct as $place => $args)
        {
            if($place > 1 && strstr($args, ':'))
            {
                $parameter = explode(":", $args);
                $parameters[$parameter[0]] = $parameter[1];
                $_GET[$parameter[0]] = $parameter[1];
            }
        }

        return $parameters;
    }

    public static function getPage()
    {
        $rpath = BASE_PATH == "/" ? NULL : BASE_PATH;

        if(self::$current_page == null) self::$current_page = (
                 str_replace('?'.$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"], NULL,
                         str_replace($rpath, NULL, $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])));

        return self::$current_page;
    }

    private static function setPage($page)
    {
        self::$current_page = $page;
        self::$page_struct = explode("/", self::$current_page);
        self::$page_struct = array_filter(self::$page_struct, 'strlen');
    }
}
class ConfigException Extends Exception {}
?>
```

After trying what @ArsalanMithani sugested, now getting:

> Warning: require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server
>   configuration by allow_url_include=0 in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/core/router.php
>   on line 55
>
> Warning:
>   require_once(http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/application/config/routes.php):
>   failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/core/router.php
>   on line 55
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/application/config/routes.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/core/router.php
>   on line 55

Comment: what is your directory structure?

Comment: @ArsalanMithani Not sure weather i understand the question. I am using linux(fedora). Installed xampp on it...

Comment: I am asking for your directory structure, your file should be properly  placed, `wp-content/theme/yourappfolder` then place your template file on your **theme root**. is it same?

Comment: index.php(the code in the question) is the script that i bought.I added first five lines in it(telling wp it is a template file). Placed the whole script in themes/twentyseventeen/yougrabber(php script)
yourgrabber folder contains: index.php and folders : application, core, files.

Comment: Now i renamed index.php(because in themes/twentyseventeen/  folder there already is an index.php) to templateindex.php and moved it to themes/twentyseventeen/. Now showing errors:
Warning: require_once(core/router.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/templateindex.php on line 11

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'core/router.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/templateindex.php on line 11

Comment: you renamed theme's `index.php`? you should not!

Comment: @ArsalanMithani I didnt rename theme index.php, I renamed script file that was also named index.php(the file that is in a question above)

Comment: i need to see `core/router.php` code, add it in your ques if you can,  you should try commenting `define("BASE_PATH..."` line also, still i didn't get the actual problem. plz dont put codes or error in comments.

Comment: @ArsalanMithani I didnt know about the rule about putting code in the comment, sry about that.
commenting out the `(define("BASE_PATH...")` doesn't change a thing

Answer (score 0):

That's seems path issue, you are using it in WordPress so you have to define relevant paths in WordPress way.

Use `get_template_directory_uri()` to get the theme path and **if** you are using **child theme** then use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

```
require( get_template_directory_uri() . '/directorypathtoscriptfiles');
```

if you have put your script like `wp-content/yourtheme/yourscriptdir` then your path should be :

`require( get_template_directory_uri() . '/yourscriptdir/core/router.php');`

**EDIT**

The warning is generated because a full URL has been used for the file that you are including, you are getting some HTML may be, this is the reason i was asking for your dir structure, although it will work if you change `allow_url_include` to `1` in `php.ini` file, but what would you do on live server? to tackle this now add `../` in your require instead of full url like below & see if that works:

do this in `router.php`

`require( '../application/config/routes.php');`

Comment: Where do i add it?Which file?

Comment: replace the requires with the above, be sure the path is correct.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't change the error.
Thing is it is showing the right path to the file now but still aint working.